# Map partial json to dto

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, mapping

I was working with rest api and I have a json on POST which I need to map to a dto. But, I have only 5 properties on json , but more than that on the dto. How do I use bean mapper to map it automatically and what about the rest of the properties. Will they be set to Null?

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot comes with [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) deserializer out-of-the-box. So, it will use the proper method (default null value or constructor properties, based on your settings). For fine tuner, see more at `JsonInclude` annotation for collections include's strategy and so. 
[JsonInclude](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? I mean if I use the dto object type as @Requestbody parameter..will it map the incoming json accordingly? Given the json has less no. Of properties than in the dto?

Comment: Correct, joining the embedded jackson databind dependecy with the @RequestBody annotation and processor by spring framework will do the job. A clear advantage of "sloppy" schema/syntax of JSON is that the incoming object doesn't need to have all the properties. Even the keys/names can be re-mapped using annotations. By the way, you must validate the bean as the client is not trustable.